# Selenium using Java Can not click the advertisement image in login.yahoo.com page

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I tried different locators type but I always get **Unable to locate element**

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Progams/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    int threadTime = 1000;
    driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'image-holder\']/img")).click();
```

I get .....

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='image-holder']/img"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'ELI-LAP', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '14.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 85.0.4183.121, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa..., userDataDir: C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:63693}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 414420227e5ad991f5af8fcdfbf67ca2
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='image-holder']/img}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a good idea to wait for the element to be clickable before clicking on it (especially if that is the first user action after the page load).

Try using a [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/) with [Expected Conditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) class:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'image-holder\']/img")).click();
```

(this goes in place of `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'image-holder\']/img")).click();`).

Comment: I did not mention it but I already tried to wait before the click but still I got the exception.